# Why am I getting this error in using nodemailer ? SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side, nodemailer, serverside-javascript

I'm building a notification application using nodemailer and I keep getting this error:

`[Error: 140735155404800:error:140770FC:SSL  routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown   protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:]`

I am using a smtp server my job has. I'm an smtp noob so any help would be appreciated.
I have sent email without any transport method but after a few emails the message object would then report my email being put in a "pending state":

`{"accepted":[],"rejected":[],"pending":[{"domain":"xxxxx.com","exchange":"xxxx.xxxx.com",...`

The above message occurs when I try to connect directly to the host as well.

Here is my code:

```
 //import nodemailer
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using SMTP
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     host: 'chelsmtp01.karmalab.net',
    port: '25',
    secure:true,
});



//email details
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'XXX', // sender address
    to: 'XXX', // list of receivers
    subject: stitle, // Subject line
    text: message, // plaintext body
    html: message 
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error)
        return console.log(error);

    console.log('Message sent: ' + JSON.stringify(info));

    //transporter.close();
});
```

I have tried setting secure to false and then I get an invalid greeting error even if I set requireTLS  true like some other forums have mentioned:

```
[Error: Invalid greeting from server:
554 chelmtp02.karmalab.net: 554 chelmtp02.karmalab.net]
code: 'EPROTOCOL',
response: '554 chelmtp02.karmalab.net',
responseCode: 554 }
```

EDIT: The SMPT server does not need user/password

EDIT: I can send email without a transport defined on my home network. I also managed to get my gmail to work as well. Could be a certificate or network issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use secure:false in the configuration options if connecting to port 25. Using true indicates that you want to start a TLS connection but port 25 starts out as plaintext and gets upgraded later

Comment: I was not on the same network as the smtp server so the firewall was keeping me out. Thanks!